# jQuery thickbox window resize from click inside window

Tags: jquery, html, css, thickbox

Question about jQuery thickbox 3.1

When the user opens the thickbox window, I have a button that they can click to show some content that's originally hidden. Right now when you click, the content shows and pushes everything down and the thickbox window gets scrollbars.  I'm trying to figure out how to  make the thickbox window resize itself dynamically depending on if the user has clicked and/or unclicked so all the content is shown instead of scrollbars. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the container of the thickbox is styled using a set height i.e:

`.thickbox{..height:300px;width:300px;}`

Trye setting the height to auto:

`.thickbox{..height:auto;width:300px;}`

Or if you have to have specific height initially, try min-height:

`.thickbox{..min-height:300px;width:300px;}`

This way your display div will expand when content is revealed.